# Resize image and display on the same position

Tags: css, image, aspect-ratio

I have added a facebook like button to the header of my website. I want it to automatically resize depending on the screen size (this seems to work). When I resize my screen though, the position changes. How can I make sure the position is also fixed?

This is the code I have. If I change the `position` attribute nothing seems to work anymore. I have tried adjusting the `top` attribute, but that doesn't do much either.

```
.header-img-1 {
  left: 45%;
  width: 8%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 72%;
}
```

Website: http://www.gelnagels-gina.be

Comment: Not sure if it is exactly what you are looking for, but if you switch `top:72%;` to `margin-top:-18px;` you will not get the position change jump.

Comment: @SRing, that doesn't seem to work, it still jumps when I resize the page.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the position to depend on screen size, you'll have to define you left, width, and top in screen size. the vh, and vw are broadly supported by browsers for most purposes. I can't tell you what the exactly numbers you should use are, because you will now be defining based off the screen size now, and not the box it is contained in. It should look something like this, except replace 10 with the correct numbers.

```
.header-img-1 {
  left: 10vw;
  width: 10vw;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10vh;
}
```

If that doesn't give you consistent behavior, you might need to define some min-width and other type of rules to make this work, depending on your exact case, or possibly use javascript to use math to make this possible and/or easier. Good luck.

Comment: Damn, didn't know that it would be so much work... I will try it as soon as I get home.

Comment: That doesn't do it either :(

Comment: the same when I used what I had. It resizes the image according to the formats I set, but the position still changes. You can also try it using the editor in Google Chrome.

Comment: Does the position change differently? If not, then be sure to use !important to be sure it's taking effect. Also, look into your inspect element.

Comment: !important overrides over css rules. It not best practice, but it's sometimes needed, and great for debugging. If it is changing differently, you probably have to fine tune it so that the ratio it's changing at is the same as the screen is changing.